# java/javac only sometimes recognised in command prompt

Tags: java, command-prompt, path-variables

I just recently started trying to work with Java, I have set the path variable and on first try it worked fine, but now whenever I boot I have to go check the variable (not set it again, just open the control panel, Advanced System Options etc... and then close it) to make it work, otherwise it just says it's not recognised as internal command, as if the path variable was actually not set. If I keep working it stays fine but if I don't do anything for about an hour the problem comes up again (without reboot).

This seems like a very weird problem and I have no idea what could cause it.

Comment: What's your Windows' version? Are you running any antivirus software?

Comment: windows 10 64bit, running avast, i'm the admin (and only user)

Comment: Can you try after disabling avast?

Comment: just tried, weirdly enough it looks like it launches faster but still the same error :/

EDIT : oh wow my bad i just realised there was an older version installed in program files while i installed the latest one to programfiles x86, i deleted one and it seems to have fixed the problem sorry for your time ^^ (also i still dont get how that worked but it seems like it's ok  now, will update if this comes back after an hour .. )